# How can I know that my data fits in memory

Tags: mysql, database-design, caching

First of all, sorry for my English I'm not good at it but I will give it my best shot:)
I have read a lot of web pages describing about how fast it will be if your data can fit in memory. The following links are an example:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,428030,428157#msg-428157

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/11/19/is-there-benefit-from-having-more-memory/

Although I tried to understand it, I am still confused about the semantics of "fit in memory"

I have some question that I would like you to help explain to me as follows

1) How can I know that my data set already fit in memory, not sure if Mysql has some tools or command to tell us about how data resides in memory, or you only have to guess?

2) I am designing an application that has a table whose schema is as follows:

**id(iht) | data1(varchar(10)) | data2(varchar(10)) | data3(text) | meta1(int) | meta2(int) | meta3(int)**

From the schema above, the minimum amount of bytes used to contain each row should
be int(4) + varchar(10) + varchar(10) + text(2) + int(4) + int(4) + int(4) = 38 bytes
which is quite small. So If I even have a million of rows, my memory should still comfortably accommodate it since it just take 38 * 1,000,000 = 38Mb.

The problem lies in the data3 column whose type is text, since this column can contain a large
amount of data. Assume that data3 would always contain a data of 10k bytes, If I had a
million of rows, It would take up to (38+10,000) * 1,000,000 = 10,038,000,000 or approximately ten gigabytes! Of course this data is not going to fit in memory.

Because in this table, each row can be read or write frequently during the lifetime of
the application, should I consider moving the data3 column to another table so that each row in this table will always be small thereby being kept in memory resulting in faster
read and write?

3) I believe that having data fit in memory can help you when it comes to reading,
I would like to know whether write operation will also benefit from it and how?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, text columns in MySQL are not always entirely kept in memory (but I may be wrong).

And of course, if your data is large enough to be bigger than your available memory, it does not fit there.

What is important is the indexing of your table, and the fact that the indexes all fit in memory.

The sure way to find out is to experiment and benchmark.